# Change order of eigenvalues and correspoding eigenvector

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, covariance

I'm struggling with some bugs in my program and try to find the mistakes.

The situation is as follows:

I have a covariance Matrix on which I perform a principal component decomposition into a Eigenvector- and Eigenvalues-Matrix (diagonal).

If I multiply the matrices which I received in the following manner:

Eigenvector * Eigenvalues * Eigenvector (transposed)

I should receive the covariance matrix back. And this is also the case. But the eigenvalues are not in decreasing order, so I wrote a loop which sorts the values in the diagonal matrix and also switches the corresponding positions in the Eigenvector Matrix. Afterwards if I multiply the matrices again, I get almost the covariance matrix, but with a deviation.

Now my question would be, have I missed something or is the operation to switch the order of the eigenvalues and respective eigenvectors not possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are your Eigenvectors normalized? I.E do they have length 1. Only then is your expression "Eigenvector * Eigenvalues * Eigenvector (transposed)" correct

Comment: Yes, i justed checked it again. They have the length 1 (to be exact: program gives sth like 1.0000000004).

Comment: In principle "switching the order" is possible. That is if the Eirgenvector is row j of the transformation matrix, the appropriate Eigenvalue appears in row j of the diagonal matrix. Can you post an easy example where this occours?

Comment: What do you mean by "but with a deviation."?

Comment: If the "deviation" is small, that might be because the length is not actually 1, but close to, then rounding errors occour. Thats a general problem of some linear solvers. Consider to use "Eigenvector * Eigenvalues * Eigenvector (inverse)" instead? That of course adds more computational complexity due to the matrix inversion.

Comment: @MarkNeuhaus I prepare sth and post it here, thx so far.
The deviation is not static. It is always different, the biggest deviation here is "10.023927076372424"

I would also consider the error might come from the roundings. But the deviation seems to high, doesnt it?

Comment: @5xum see post above. Deviation is max at about 10. It seems quite high

Comment: @serij What is this "deviation", exactly? Can you give an example of the matrix at which this occurs?

Comment: @5xum Alright I made a smaller dataset:

[Link to Excel Sheet Online](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgDMRHUZTc5QhlBN503aeUDb2v2J)

After the sorting to descending, I have almost no deviation. The max value is: 3.552713678800501E-14

In this case I took 3 datapoints into the calculation. With the real data there are 120. So does it depend on the amount of data?